# Double Summation Indices Switching

Tags: summation

How can you "rigorously" prove the following mathematical fact?
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^k a_{kj} = \sum_{j=0}^m \sum_{k=j}^m a_{kj}
$$

Visually, it is clear they are equivalent (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1395905/635480)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063704/fubinis-theorem-for-series-with-dependent-indices

Comment: If you set $a_{k,j}=0$ for $j>k$ this follows from $\sum_j\sum_k a_{kj}=\sum_k\sum_ja_{kj}$.